# Как добавить класс элементу Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, javascript-events, vuetify

я свсем новичек в vue, столкнулся с маленькой проблемой, буду рад любой помощи.
Я использую библиотеку **vue-scrollto**, в документации  нашел описаный ниже метод OnDone, где я  и  добавляю целевому єлементу нужный  класс.

Моя проблема в том, что я не знаю как удалить класс при клике на другой эелемент.

```
a.nav-item(href="#item-1" v-scroll-to="{el: '#item-1', onDone: onDone}").scrollactive-item

methods: {
onDone: function(element) {
  console.log(element)
  element.classList.add('activeItem');
},
```

},

Comment: На мой скромный взгляд, если вы новичок во vue, то не стоит вообще использовать какие-то сторонние библиотеки. Во-первых, мало кто использует ту самую, по которой у вас вопрос, а значит и ответ вы врядли получите быстро, а во-вторых вы лишаете себя возможности глубже изучить инструмент. Если бы не эта либа, я бы вам смог что-то подсказать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сохранять ссылку на текущий активный элемент в `data`, и при прокрутке к другому элементу сначала удалять класс `activeItem` у этого элемента, а потом записывать ссылку на него в `data` и назначать ему класс `activeItem`.

Это может выглядеть как-то так:

```js
data() {
    return {
        activeElement: undefined,
    }
},
methods: {
    onDone(el) {
        if (this.activeElement) {
            this.activeElement.classList.remove("activeItem")
        }

        this.activeElement = el;
        this.activeElement.classList.add("activeItem")
    }
},
```

Попробуйте так.

Удачи!

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо, работает!